# Ember Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yield' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We are getting an error 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'yield' of undefined
for the following hbs code;

```
<button {{if isButtonEnabled 'enabled' 'disabled'}}>Test</button>
```

isButtonEnabled is a property defined on my corresponding controller

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) and add a link to your question?

Comment: What Ember versions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to flip your condition and do this. I just had this exact problem and this was the solution.

```
<button disabled={{isButtonDisabled}}>Test<button>
```

Comment: You can't arbitrarily add attributes to HTML elements like in OP's code because Ember doesn't have a way to hook into the HTML to then update it.

Comment: Need to mention that if isButtonDisabled returns boolean the disabled attribute will be rendered either way. Only NULL will remove the attribute